# Camera capture using Html5 input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the below line of code in order to invoke camera from my web application.

```
<input type="file" id="capture" accept="image/*; capture=camera" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

Using this, I am able to get the pop up with options of "Choose existing photo" and "Take Picture", when the application is opened in iOS6.
But I want to open up camera capture directly rather then getting this pop up and then select "Take Picture" option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the rest of the code where you get to camera capture etc.

Comment: code used for camera capture is :<div  class="clsAttachViewLabel" align="middle">
<label class="clsCaptureLabel" data-click="onClickTake" >Take a Photo</label>
</div>

<input type="file" id="capture" accept="image/*; capture=camera" style="visibility:hidden;">

In JS File :
function onClickTake() {
 
 $("#capture").click();
 
}

Comment: Is there any way by which I can modify even the options which appear in pop up in iOS6 For example:options we get in pop up are "Choose Existing","Take Photo or Video" and "Cancel".If I want only "Take Photo" option,how can I display that alone in pop up

Comment: Those buttons are part of iOS and are immutable. There is currently nothing you can do to change/bypass this menu from a web app.

Comment: @Kiara_2013 any chance of marking an answer? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

Works in Chrome on Android (at least).

Comment: It works in Chrome browser on Android.
Why it does not work on Android native browser?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible as per the specification for security/privacy reasons:

> The user agent SHOULD NOT enable any device for media capture, such as a microphone or camera, until a user interaction giving implicit consent is completed.

http://www.w3.org/TR/capture-api/#security

An alternative is to use [getUserMedia](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/). This still shows a dialog requesting user permission but in some browsers the user can choose to hide it after granting access to a domain.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using on Android? This page indicates that it doesn't work on Chrome but should work on the Android browser and on iOS Safari. It doesn't specifically mention Chrome for Android. I tested the tag with the Chrome browser on my LG G6 phone and it didn't work. I wasn't able to test Android browser--it seems to be missing on my phone.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=html-media-capture